# Update notification adding new lines to the current one

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, android-notifications, android-notification-bar

I want to show a GCM notification which is multiline, and that notification should be updated by adding new lines. I mean, I receive and show a first notification, then it is shown showing the text "Notification 1". But then, when a second notification is received, I want to update the current active notification by adding a second line that says "Notification 2". How could I achieve that? I've thought about setting the NotificationCompat.InboxStyle as static, so the lines may be added, but the problem then is: How could I clear that static data if there's no click callback? I can do it on the PendingIntent, but I think that it would not be a nice way to proceed.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried what [the documentation suggests](http://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/managing.html)? And if that didn't work, what exactly was the problem?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The documentation tells how to update a notification, but it will change the current text, while what I want is to update that text by adding a new line, but without removing the current one

Comment: In API level 23 you can call `getActiveNotifications` to retrieve your `Notification`, and I'd expect that you then can get the content text from it. Otherwise, save the old text somewhere.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've read about that, but we must support devices from SDK version 16. I've thought about setting the NotificationCompat.InboxStyle as static, so the lines may be added, but the problem then is: How could I clear that static data if there's no click callback? I can do it on the PendingIntent, but I think that it would not be a nice way to proceed.